# Trying to code Haug's 4.19.7 Double-Barrier Binary Asymmetrical

Tags: options, valuation

The following Clojure code correctly outputs the table in section 4.19.6 of "The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas", but I'm wildly out on the asymmetrical in 4.19.7.

```
(defn double-barrier-binary
  [S L U T r b v asymmetric?]
  (let [R 1
        Z (Math/log (/ U L))
        v-sq (Math/pow v 2)
        term (- (/ (* 2 b) v-sq) 1)
        alpha (* -0.5 term)
        beta (- (* -0.25 (Math/pow term 2)) (* 2 (/ r v-sq)))
        N 100]
    (loop [i 1 result 0]
      (let [i-pi (* i Math/PI)
            i-pi-Z (/ i-pi Z)
            i-pi-Z-sq (Math/pow i-pi-Z 2)
            log-s-l (Math/log (/ S L))
            sin-pi-log (Math/sin (* i-pi-Z log-s-l))
            exp-term (Math/exp (* -0.5 (* (- i-pi-Z-sq beta) (* v-sq T))))]
        (case asymmetric?
          true (if (= N i)
                  (float (* R (Math/pow (/ S L) alpha) result))
                  (let [i-pi-2 (/ 2 i-pi)
                        t-top (- beta (* i-pi-Z-sq exp-term))
                        t-btm (- i-pi-Z-sq beta)
                        log-Z (- 1 (/ log-s-l Z))]
                    (recur (inc i) (+ result (* i-pi-2 (/ t-top t-btm) sin-pi-log) log-Z))))
          false (if (= N i)
                  (float result)
                  (let [K 10
                        i-pi-K-Z (/ (* 2 i-pi K) (Math/pow Z 2))
                        sla (Math/pow (/ S L) alpha)
                        sua (Math/pow (/ S U) alpha)
                        neg-1-i (Math/pow -1 i)
                        t-top (- sla (* neg-1-i sua))
                        t-btm (+ (Math/pow alpha 2) i-pi-Z-sq)]
                    (recur (inc i) (+ result (* i-pi-K-Z (/ t-top t-btm) sin-pi-log exp-term))))))))))

(letfn [(nk [L H v] (double-barrier-binary 100 L H 0.25 0.05 0.03 v false))]
  (println (map (fn [v] (str "\n" (mapv #(nk (first v) (second v) %) [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5]))) [[80 120] [85 115] [90 110] [95 105]])))
```

To try the above, paste into the left panel of https://repl.it/languages/clojure and hit 'run'. Grateful if anyone has working code (any language will do) as I just can't see how I've interpreted the asymmetric formula incorrectly.

Comment: The sections you mention are from this book right: "The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas", Espen Haug, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, a bit of an assumption there... I imagined it was a bible in this context as I've seen it mentioned before

Comment: No worries, I just think it's good to be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question - it appears that I can't read formulas correctly. The final
$$
\left( 1 - \dfrac{ln(S/L)}{Z} \right)
$$
term at the bottom of page 181 of Haug is only added once at the end of the iteration, not on each loop. Hui's original work also brackets similarly. I assumed the square brackets included it each time. So back to maths classes for me. Revised code (Clojure again for those (few?) using it in this domain, convergence checking not yet done):

```
(defn double-barrier-binary
  [S L U T r b v asymmetric?]
  (let [R 10
        Z (Math/log (/ U L))
        v-sq (Math/pow v 2)
        term (- (/ (* 2 b) v-sq) 1)
        alpha (* -0.5 term)
        beta (- (* -0.25 (Math/pow term 2)) (* 2 (/ r v-sq)))
        log-s-l (Math/log (/ S L))
        log-Z (- 1 (/ log-s-l Z))
        N 100]
    (loop [i 1 result 0]
      (let [i-pi (* i Math/PI)
            i-pi-Z (/ i-pi Z)
            i-pi-Z-sq (Math/pow i-pi-Z 2)
            sin-pi-log (Math/sin (* i-pi-Z log-s-l))
            exp-term (Math/exp (* -0.5 (* (- i-pi-Z-sq beta) (* v-sq T))))]
        (case asymmetric?
          true (if (= N i)
                  (float (* R (Math/pow (/ S L) alpha) (+ result log-Z)))
                  (let [i-pi-2 (/ 2 i-pi)
                        t-top (- beta (* i-pi-Z-sq exp-term))
                        t-btm (- i-pi-Z-sq beta)]
                    (recur (inc i) (+ result (* i-pi-2 (/ t-top t-btm) sin-pi-log)))))
          false (if (= N i)
                  (float result)
                  (let [K 10
                        i-pi-K-Z (/ (* 2 i-pi K) (Math/pow Z 2))
                        sla (Math/pow (/ S L) alpha)
                        sua (Math/pow (/ S U) alpha)
                        neg-1-i (Math/pow -1 i)
                        t-top (- sla (* neg-1-i sua))
                        t-btm (+ (Math/pow alpha 2) i-pi-Z-sq)]
                    (recur (inc i) (+ result (* i-pi-K-Z (/ t-top t-btm) sin-pi-log exp-term))))))))))
```

Comment: Well done! I saw your edit: Please try to gain control of your original account and accept the answer you just gave. [Accounts can be merged](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Thanks Bob - not sure how I crossed wires there...